# gradle java: pre-process resources before building jar

Tags: java, gradle, resources

Gradle java plugin:

```
src/main/java
         resources/foo-config.xml
```

The foo-config.xml has some variables to replace, for example, @VERSION_NUMBER@.
How to process it before generating jar.

The foo-config.xml should be copied to the build dir for processing to avoid any changes under src directory.

Answer (score 3):

Configure the `processResources` task which is a copy task. You can add some filtering there. Make sure to set the right encoding for the filtering to not corrupt special characters if you have some, e. g. like

```
processResources {
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION_NUMBER: version])
}
```

Comment: I will verify it and accept it as answer if it works. Where can I find the docs on what I can do with processResources? thanks.

Comment: Ist's a task of type Copy: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html